# My function doesn't return the right value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with the following function:

```
function getLengthData(date, driverId) {
    var length = [];
    $
    .get('http://xx/x/x/' + date + '/' + driverId + '')
    .done(function (data) {
        var test = data.length;
        length.push(test);
    });
    return length;
}
```

This returns nothing while it should return an array with 1 element, the length of the data array. The next function uses the same way and works perfectly:

```
function getStopsFromStorage() {
    var stops = [];
    _2XLMobileApp.db.stopsData.load().done(function (result) {
        $.each(result, function () {
            stops.push(this.Id);
        });
    })
    return stops;
}
```

I kinda have an idea what the problem is but no idea how to fix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thx

Comment: What does your network & console pane say in your debugger?

Comment: You're probably running into the difference between a synchronous call and an asynchronous one.

Comment: Is this not an async probelm? .get is asynchronous so while that is happening execution continues and returns the empty array (you say nothing is returned but are you sure its not an empty array?). The length is only actually changed when the get returns, too late for it to have been useful for you...

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: The OP said that one call worked, so I think `_2XLMobileApp.db.stopsData.load().done` is actually synchronous.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski:
Yeah it's an empty array, thats what I meant sry. Ok I understand the problem. Forgot about AJAX. Do you have an example for that Jonathan?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Don't confuse things like `done` with being synchronous. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Comment: @DaveNewton: I know jQuery's call.  I know nothing about 2XLMobileApp.  But if the OP says that the results of `_2XLMobileApp.db.stopsData.load().done` are available before the following line (`return`) is called, then this is not using jQuery's Deferred.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I see what you're saying, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already learned, you won't be able to use `return` with asynchronous functions like `$.get()`. The `return` statement that follows `$.get()` will occur before the request has actually completed.

One option you can do is to adjust the function to accept its own callback. Another is to `return` a [Deferred/Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) so the calling code can apply the callback itself.

Better still may be to support both like `$.get()` and other Ajax methods.

```
function getLengthData(date, driverId, callback) {
    return $.get('http://xx/x/x/' + date + '/' + driverId + '')
        .then(function (data) {
            return data.length;
        })
        .done(callback);
}
```

```
getLengthData('2013-07-31', '1234', function (length) {
    // use `length` here
});

getLengthData('2013-07-31', '1234').done(function (length) {
    // use `length` here
});
```

This snippet does require jQuery 1.8+ as it makes use of [chaining deferreds with `.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). In short, the `return data.length` within `getLengthData` just changes the arguments for any further `.done()` callbacks, such as `callback`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jMrVP/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your host and port match in `http://194.78.58.118:9001`?

This can be [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem.

**EDIT:**

[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is **asynchronous** JavaScript and XML. So you returning value *before* you get response from server.

Comment: Yes thats not the problem. Inside the done function of the get request I can get the length.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that could be it. Is there anyway I can fix the problem or try to find another way?

Comment: You need to find another way. For example have all your code that require this variable in function scope and call this function at AJAX success. There is no other way to deal with asynchrony requests.